# dotnet core install via official script

Tags: .net-core

Trying to install sdk from powershell script and getting 404

Running script for windows from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script

This is the official script: https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1

When i take url out and try to get from browser, I get BlobNotFound

[image]

I would have thought this script is maintained and the location of the zip would always be available.

Can someone point me to the location where I can get zip?

I want to write script to automate this and not do through installer

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug at https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues. The script was supposed to always return a working URL.

Comment: thanks @omajid. See https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1255